# how can I optimize this file diff in Python?

Tags: python

Tried to optimize this file diif with less code but is slow - CSVs are large
how can I optimize this file diff in Python?

```
 with open('2020-01-26.csv', 'r') as t1, open('2020-02-02.csv', 'r') as t2:
    fileone = t1.readlines()
    filetwo = t2.readlines()

with open('update.csv', 'w') as outFile:
    cnt = 0
        for line in filetwo:
            cnt += 1
            print(cnt)
            if line not in fileone:
                outFile.write(line)
```

Comment: You are performing a sequential search. Are the files sorted?

Comment: Do you have any duplicate lines / do you need to account for duplicate lines?

Comment: @JMD no sorting just need a new file with the diff

Comment: @ExaltedBagel  may have duplicates but its ok since I  just need a new file with the diff between both files

Answer (score 1):

`line not in fileone` is slow, just make it a set with `fileone = set(t1.readlines())`. And then the bottleneck will be the `print` so you should remove that, too.

The `in` (and `not in`) check takes linear time for lists but only constant time for sets. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity.

Comment: Hi Heap, this looks promising. Can you write out the full code snippet?

Comment: Why? You already have the rest of the code. Just add `set(` and `)` in your code.

Comment: I just edit this part?        ```    #if line not in fileone:
         fileone = set(t1.readlines())
         outFile.write(fileone)```

Comment: @RafaelDaCosta No, just add `set(` and `)` like I showed.

Comment: Hi Heap, What did the set() method do to improve?

Comment: @RafaelDaCosta Changes the `in` check from linear time to constant time. See https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity

Comment: Hi Heap, I left the in conditional in the see ---https://github.com/dacosta-rafael/py-file-diff/blob/master/parse.py

Answer (score 0):

I would use pandas for this. The upside is that you can specify different kinds of joins (left, right, outer, inner). This way you can find the exact difference of two csv files.

```
import pandas as pd  

t1 = pd.read_csv('2020-01-26.csv')
t2 = pd.read_csv('2020-02-02.csv')
df = t1.merge(t2, how='inner', indicator=False)

df.head(10) # This shows the first 10 lines of the difference
df.to_csv('update.csv') # This saves the difference as .csv file
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use difflib for this task:

```
import difflib

text1 = open("2020-01-26.csv").readlines()
text2 = open("2020-02-02.csv").readlines()
diff = difflib.unified_diff(text1, text2)

# Printing all lines we just see a classic diff display
for line in diff:
    print(line)

lines = list(diff)[2:]
added = [line[1:] for line in lines if line[0] == '+']
removed = [line[1:] for line in lines if line[0] == '-']
```

I am not sure how you want to handle the difference (added vs removed) so I just put them into two separate lists for easy manipulation.